# Prove that you can choose three of spotlights.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, convex-hulls

The plane is illuminated by several spotlights, each of which illuminates a half-plane. Prove that you can choose three of these spotlights, which also illuminate the entire plane?

Comment: Well, if all of the spotlights in the same orientation, this is false.

Comment: @JoshuaWang: I suspect that the first four words are to be understood as implying that the entire plane is illuminated, as otherwise the result necessarily fails. It’s also clear that the collection of spotlights must be finite.

Comment: How is your problem related to discrete mathematics, graph theory and problem solving?

Comment: There is a solution [here](https://f2.org/maths/halfplane-soln.html). It’s terse, and you’ll probably have to work a bit to follow it, but it’s complete.

Answer (score 2):

One of the half planes must cover the final uncovered space (which is convex).

The convex shape it covers must have a closest point to the covering line (or a parallel in which case we can solve with two spotlights).

The covering line and the two lines radiating from the closest point cover the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing the other answer to make it more understandable (to me). The proof is by induction on $n$, the base case $n=3$ being obvious.

Remove one of the spotlights, which covers a half-plane $H$. If the remaining $n-1$ spotlights cover the plane, then you can select $3$ of them which cover the plane by the inductive hypothesis.

If not, then there will be an uncovered region which is a convex polygon. Let $P$ be a vertex of this polygon whose distance to $H$ is minimal, and let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the edges adjacent to $P$. There is a spotlight whose boundary contains $e_1$, and points away from the uncovered region, therefore pointing towards the complement of $H$. Same goes for $e_2$. Therefore, some thought should convince you that $H$, together with the spotlights for $e_1$ and $e_2$, will cover the whole space.